# How to print out a string from mysql to javascript into mutiple lines

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, pug

i'm new to mysql and javascript and im just wondering how to get a string from mysql database and output them in different line.

right now i'm using express.js and this is my code in name.jade file:

```
each val in database
    h4 name: #{val.Name}
    p.
       address: #{val.Address}<br>
```

my expect out put should be

```
address: 1234 some street
         canada
         l3l 2k2
```

but what i have is

```
address: 1234 some street canada l3l 2k2
```

Comment: You're probably also new to HTML/CSS. `name.jade` is a [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) file which renders HTML. You need to figure out what HTML you should render to generate that multiline output. It'll most probably also be a job for CSS to align them into columns. So I'd say you learn more about HTML/CSS.

Comment: i figured it out. when im calling #{val.name}, # atuomaticly change the content from database to string representation so it become &lt and &gt. ! will keep the database content unchanged